# Pandas package dealing with ugly column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access some columns in a spreadsheet that has ugly column names (e.g. spaces, parens,...) using pandas in python. I have this code snippet:

```
colnames= ['Name', 'Powered On', 'Connection State', 'Idle','Memory (GB)', 'Mem Recomm','Disk Recomm', 'Disk (GB)', 'ThinProvDisk', 'Max Read IO', 'Mac Write IO', 'IOPS Avg', 'Max VDisk Read (MBps)', 'Max VDisk Write (MBps)', 'CPU Avg (MHz)', 'vCPUs', 'vCPU Recommended', 'CPU|Usage', 'vCenter', 'Guest OS', 'Guest IP', 'VMTools status', 'Networks', 'Cluster', 'Datacenter', 'Current Host', 'Folder', 'Memory Hot Add', 'vCPU Hot Add', 'VM Version', 'vSphere Tag', 'Template', 'Datastore(s)', 'Datastores']

data = pd.read_excel(str(sys.argv[1]), names = colnames)
names = data.['Powered On'].tolist()
for x in (names):
  print(x)
```

I am trying to extract the list of the Powered On column but ultimately will need to extract the others in various combinations. I keep getting a syntax error on the line:

```
names = data.['Powered On'].tolist()
```

that implies the square brace and quotes are syntactically invalid. Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI, I cannot modify the inbound spreadsheet as it is generated by another team and they refuse to clean it up. Thanks!!!!! Chuck

Comment: Get rid of the period after `data`

Comment: AWESOME!!!!. I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can extract a particular column(s) from your dataframe. To extract a single column, you can do either of the following:

```
data['Powered On']
```

Or if there are no spaces or punctuation in your desired column name:

```
data.Name
```

Note that this is not the recommended syntax as it can conflict with reserved names, such as `data.index`, `data.columns`, etc.

To extract multiple columns, pass a list:

```
data[['Name','Powered On','Connection State']]
```

Further documentation for indexing and selecting data is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should use `data['Powered On']`, without the period. You can use the period for simpler column names, but then without the square brackets and ''. 
`data['Idle']` would be the same as `data.Idle`